# Refactor simple rails code for specifying active li on navigation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to set an li class of active based on what page the user is on.

I have 4 navigation elements and they all look something like this:

```
<% if @activeLi == "home" %>          
    <li class="active">
<% else %>
    <li>
<% end %>
    <%= link_to :controller => "home" do %>
        <span>Home</span>
    <% end %>
</li>
```

and then in each controller I just set @activeLi like this:

```
def index
    @activeLi = "about"
end
```

I know this is pretty basic stuff, but i'm just wondering if there is an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I know one way you can simplify this and thats by getting rid of the need to use those nasty instance variables.

```
<li class="<%= controller_name == "home" ? 'active': '' %>">
    <%= link_to :controller => "home" do %>
        <span>Home</span>
    <% end %>
</li>
```

Comment: As the newbie I am to RoR, i was not aware of the controller_name function. Thanks for that.

Comment: There are hundreds of those really. I only learned about controller_name a few months ago myself. I would really recommend downloading the (Pry Gem)[http://pry.github.com/] and working that into your development process. Being able to pause the execution of a script or the rendering of a webpage and then check what all available variables and methods are in scope has been a real life saver.